# Texreg table incomplete

Tags: r, r-markdown, texreg

I am trying to finish my texreg table for my glm output and my table looks like this:

[image]

but I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Am I missing a step? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying `"results='asis'"` when you open the chunk where you are gonna run de texreg table?

Like this:

```
{r, results='asis'}

texreg(model)
```